# Combine columns of three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have three temp tables in SQL:

Temp1

```
UserID   Score_1
   123       100
   456       200
```

Temp2

```
UserID   Score_2
   456       300
```

Temp3

```
UserID   Score_3
   123       400
   789       500
```

I want to combine all these three tables into one as

```
UserID   Score_1   Score_2   Score_3
   123       100      NULL       400
   456       200       300      NULL
   789      NULL      NULL       500
```

Is there any way we could achieve this through SQL? I tried using each joins and even some combinations of union and joins, but couldn't get the format properly.

```
select P.Score_1 , U.Score_2 , A.Score_3 from #mytemp1 P join #mytemp2 U on P.UserID = U.UserID join  #mytemp3 A on P.UserID = A.UserID
```

```
select P.Score_1 , U.Score_2 , A.Score_3 from #mytemp1 P left join #mytemp2 U on P.UserID = U.UserID left join  #mytemp3 A on P.UserID = A.UserID
```

```
select P.Score_1 , U.Score_2 , A.Score_3 from #mytemp1 P right join #mytemp2 U on P.UserID = U.UserID right join  #mytemp3 A on P.UserID = A.UserID
```

```
select allData.UserID, P.Score_1 , U.Score_2 , A.Score_3 
from (select UserID from #mytemp1 union 
  select UserID from #mytemp2 union 
  select UserID from #mytemp3 ) allData 
join #mytemp1 t1 ON allData.UserID = t1.UserID 
join #mytemp2 t2 ON allData.UserID = t2.UserID 
join #mytemp3 t3 ON allData.UserID = t3.UserID
```

Each table may contain a different number of rows, the rows count can be even 0.

Thanks in advance,
Jonathon

Comment: Can you post an example of something that you tried?

Comment: Hi @PinnyM, I have edited the question with what I have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.UserID, t2.UserID, t3.UserID) as UserID, t1.Score_1, t2.Score_2, t3.Score_3
FROM Temp1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN Temp2 t2 ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID
FULL OUTER JOIN Temp3 t3 ON COALESCE(t1.UserID, t2.UserID) = t3.UserID
```

SQL fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d685/1)

The difference between a FULL OUTER JOIN and a LEFT (or RIGHT) OUTER JOIN, is that the FULL join will permit some missing keys (`UserID` in this case) in *both* tables and still return results, while the LEFT and RIGHT variants require at least one of the tables to contain all the keys (which table depends on if you use LEFT or RIGHT).

Note the use of COALESCE on the second join - this is required because we won't know which table (if any) may have a match for Temp3.  Leaving this out would require guessing which one - and if a match actually occurs only in the other table, you'll end up with duplicate rows.  Using COALESCE here avoids the need to make that guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.UserID,T2.UserID,T3.UserID) as UserID,T1.Score_1,T2.Score_2,T3.Score_3
FROM Temp1 T1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     Temp2 T2 ON T1.UserID=T2.UserID FULL OUTER JOIN
     Temp3 T3 ON T1.UserID=T3.UserID
```

Result:

```
USERID  SCORE_1  SCORE_2    SCORE_3
123     100      (null)     400
456     200      300        (null)
789     (null)   (null)     500
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6b0d/1).

If you want to replace `NULL` values with 0 you can use `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.UserID,T2.UserID,T3.UserID) as UserID,ISNULL(T1.Score_1,0) as Score_1,ISNULL(T2.Score_2,0) as Score_2,ISNULL(T3.Score_3,0) as Score_3
FROM Temp1 T1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     Temp2 T2 ON T1.UserID=T2.UserID FULL OUTER JOIN
     Temp3 T3 ON T1.UserID=T3.UserID
```

Example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6b0d/4).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a `full outer join`:

```
select coalesce(temp1.UserId, temp2.UserId, temp3.UserId) as UserId,
       temp1.Score_1, temp2.Score_2, temp3.Score_3
from temp1 full outer join
     temp2
     on temp2.UserId = temp1.UserId full outer join
     temp3
     on temp3.UserId = coalesce(temp1.UserId, temp2.UserId);
```

Another approach starts with all the ids in a single "driver" table and then uses `left outer join`:

```
select ids.UserId, temp1.Score_1, temp2.Score_2, temp3.Score_3
from (select UserId from temp1 union 
      select UserId from temp2
      select UserId from temp3
     ) ids left outer join
     temp1
     on temp1.UserId = ids.UserId left outer join
     temp2
     on temp2.UserId = ids.UserId full outer join
     temp3
     on temp3.UserId = ids.UserId;
```

Note that with this method, you don't need the `coalesce()` in the `on` conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```
select coalesce(a.userid,b.userid,c.userid),score1,score2,score3 from #t a 
full outer join #t1 b on a.userid=b.userid 
full outer join #t2 c on a.userid=c.userid
```

## [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17927)

In case if your data is like what said in comments

```
create table #t(userid int,score1 int)
insert into #t values(123,100),(456,200)

create table #t1(userid int,score2 int)
insert into #t1 values(456,300),(789,700)

create table #t2(userid int,score3 int)
insert into #t2 values(123,400),(789,500)


select coalesce(a.userid,b.userid,c.userid),score1,score2,score3 from #t a full outer join #t1 b on a.userid=b.userid full outer join #t2 c on coalesce(a.userid,b.userid)=c.userid
```

you need a `coalesce`

Comment: In the event that tables `b` and `c` would share a common `UserId` not included in `a`, you'll have duplicate rows (although this doesn't occur in the sample data provided).  You can see this if you added a row for UserId `789` in table `b`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select allData.UserID, t1.Score_1, t2.Score_2, t3.Score_3
  from (select UserID from Temp1 union
        select UserID from Temp2 union
        select UserID from Temp3
       ) allData
left join Temp1 t1 ON allData.UserID = t1.UserID
left join Temp2 t2 ON allData.UserID = t2.UserID
left join Temp3 t3 ON allData.UserID = t3.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to get the result you want, but the easiest IMO is a simple `UNION` and `GROUP`

```
Select UserID, Max(Score_1) Score_1, Max(Score_2) Score_2, Max(Score_3) Score_3
FROM   (SELECT UserID, Score_1, NULL Score_2, NULL Score_3
        FROM Temp1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT UserID, NULL Score_1, Score_2, NULL Score_3
        FROM Temp2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT UserID, NULL Score_1, NULL Score_2, Score_3
        FROM Temp3) a
GROUP BY UserID
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6b0d/12)